# Get a specific tag with a part of the string beautiful Soup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i have many web pages to **scrape**.
some of them have 4/5 `<p>` tags, but they have same string in their `<p>` tags.
how can i access the whole contents of the `<p>` tag.
`(newbie)`

Comment: Could you create a Minimal, Reproducible Example as per the instructions on asking a question see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: your question is not cleat as per SO, but as per now you can use different class.

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap